# Homotopy groups of K3 

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, tag-removed, gt.geometric-topology

Let X be a K3 surface and $Y=X/\mathbb{Z}_2$, an Enrique surface.
Long exact sequence of homotopy groups corresponding to fiberaion $\pi:X\to Y$, says that $\pi_2(X)=\pi_2(Y)$, while we know $H_2(X)$ and $H_2(Y)$ are very different.

What are $\pi_2(X)$ and $\pi_2(Y)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hurewicz theorem says that for a simply connected space $X$, $\pi_2(X)\cong H_2(X,\mathbb Z)$. So $\pi_2(K3)\cong H_2(K3,\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z^{22}$. Here is a link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem

Comment: Don't you mean 22?

Comment: Sure Will :) that was a misprint